# Maven dependencies

Tags: maven

Добрый день!

У меня есть модуль проекта с зависимостью (другим модулем).

При сборке вижу вот такие строки:

> Could not find metadata com.somename.rss.sdn:nc-side:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (c:\m2)
>
> Failure to find .../maven-metadata.xml in https://nexussrv.somename.com/content/repositories/central was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until...

И таким образом он ищет еще в нескольких репозиториях.
Артефакт присутствует в локальном репозитории, почему он не ищет там?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день. 
Попробуйте сначала сделать `deploy` в вашей зависимости `com.somename.rss.sdn:nc-side`